# JavaFX ListView and TableView CSS for non focused selection

Tags: java, css, listview, javafx

I literally have nothing in my Stylesheet but

```
.root {
    -fx-accent: #a9d5f9;
}
```

I want to change this color. Is the color for selected row when table is no longer focused.

[image]

Been looking for a while and i found pretty much everything but this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These two selectors should do it for `ListView`s:

```
.list-cell:filled:selected {
    -fx-background: orange;
}

.list-view:focused > .virtual-flow > .clipped-container > .sheet > .list-cell:filled:selected {
    -fx-background: -fx-selection-bar;
}
```

To have the same coloring in `TableView`s (both cell and row selection), you can add more selectors:

```
.table-row-cell:filled:selected,
.tree-table-row-cell:filled:selected,
.table-row-cell:filled > .table-cell:selected,
.tree-table-row-cell:filled > .tree-table-cell:selected,
.list-cell:filled:selected {
    -fx-background: orange;
}

.table-view:focused > .virtual-flow > .clipped-container > .sheet > .table-row-cell:filled:selected,
.tree-table-view:focused > .virtual-flow > .clipped-container > .sheet > .tree-table-row-cell:filled:selected,
.table-view:focused > .virtual-flow > .clipped-container > .sheet > .table-row-cell .table-cell:selected,
.tree-table-view:focused > .virtual-flow > .clipped-container > .sheet > .tree-table-row-cell .tree-table-cell:selected ,
.list-view:focused > .virtual-flow > .clipped-container > .sheet > .list-cell:filled:selected {
    -fx-background: -fx-selection-bar;
}
```

Note: these selectors targeting even `TreeTableViews`.

**The result:**

[image]

Comment: -fx-selection-bar had the same effect as accent. But that gray color remains the same.

Comment: It only works on ListViews to me, for some reason TableView ignores it.

Comment: @WesosdeQueso: I just read the title and did not notice that you have `TableView`s on the pictures. Updated the answer.